# Remove one querystring parameter from a URL with multiple querystring parameters

Tags: php, str-replace

I would like to remove a querystring parameter from a url that may contain multiple. I have succeeded in doing this using `str_replace` so far like this:

```
$area_querystring = urlencode($_GET['area']);
str_replace('area=' . $area_querystring, '', $url);
```

`preg_replace` also works, like this:

```
preg_replace('~(\?|&)area=[^&]*~', '$1', $url)
```

Either works fine for most URLs. For example:

```
http://localhost:8000/country/tw/?area=Taipei%2C+Taiwan&fruit=bananas
```

Becomes:

```
http://localhost:8000/country/tw/?&fruit=bananas
```

However, if the querystring contains an apostrophe html entity, nothing happens at all. E.g.:

```
http://localhost:8000/country/cn/?area=Shanghai%2C+People%27s+Republic+of+China&fruit=bananas
```

The `%27` part of the url (an apostrophe) seems to be the cause.

To be clear, I don't wish to remove all of the URL after the last `/`, just the `area` querystring portion (the `fruit=bananas` part of the url should remain). Also, the `area` parameter does not always appear in the same place in the URL, sometimes it may appear after other querystring parameters e.g.

```
http://localhost:8000/country/tw/?lang=taiwanese&area=Taipei%2C+Taiwan&fruit=bananas
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by it "fails"--does nothing happen at all, or it only trims out part of what it is supposed to? I'm suspecting that the $url variable is not actually URL-encoded yet, perhaps give the following a try: str_replace('area=' . $_GET['area'], '', $url);

Comment: @DashRantic question updated - nothing happens at all

Answer (score 1):

You can use the GET array and filter out the area key. Then rebuild the url with http_build_query.  Like this:

```
$url = 'http://localhost:8000/country/cn/?area=Shanghai%2C+People%27s+Republic+of+China&fruit=bananas';
$filtered = array_filter($_GET, function ($key) {
    return $key !== 'area';
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
$parsed = parse_url($url);
$query = http_build_query($filtered);
$result = $parsed['scheme'] . "://" . $parsed['host'] . $parsed['path'] . "?" . $query;
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need `urlencode()` -- I'm guessing your `$url` variable is not yet encoded, so if there are any characters like an apostrophe, there won't be a match.

So:

```
$area_querystring = $_GET['area'];
```

should do the trick! No URL encoding/decoding needed.